# Does react allow to pass semantically different sets of children?

Tags: reactjs

I've recently worked a bit in Blazor (C# WebAssembly), and I've seen the following tutorial which shows that Blazor is able to differentiate child components based on name: https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2019/12/blazor-generic-typed-component.html

Child component:

```
<h3>Card</h3>
<div class="card text-center">
    @CardHeader
    @CardBody
    @CardFooter
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment CardHeader { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment CardBody { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment CardFooter { get; set; }
}
```

RenderFragment is comparable to e.g. JSX.Element in react-ts

Parent:

```
<Card>
    <CardHeader>
        <div class="card-header">
           My Templated Component
        </div>
    </CardHeader>
    <CardBody>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5>Welcome To Template Component</h5>
        </div>
    </CardBody>
    <CardFooter>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            Click Here
        </div>
    </CardFooter>        
</Card>
```

While this use case is not crazy enlightening, I thought this would be a very nice fit for generic components which e.g. allow a different set of children for a loading state, a loaded state and an error state to be passed from the parent.

I'm aware that I could just pass this as props in react, and I could also manually go through the `children` array, but I'm wondering whether React offers a similar style of passing sets of children differentiated by name, similar to the style shown above.